# Error: options page not found when I try to save the changes made in my settings page

Tags: settings-api, plugin-options

I'm developing a plugin... everything was fine but suddenly when I try to save the plugin settings... I found with the error that says the page options not found..

I was looking for some answer but not one fix my error... Following some code that makes the settings page and save the options in the database:

**admin.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * This file contains the necesary functions to display the admin area of the plugin
 *
 * @author  Ezequiel Cattaneo <webstower@gmail.com>
 *
 * @link    https://webstower.com.ar/wtdomcheck
 * @since   1.0.0
 *
 **/

require_once WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_DIR.'admin/class/class-admin.php';

$wtdomadmin = '';

//All the magic is done here!
if ( class_exists('admin') ) {
    
    $wtdomadmin = new admin();
    $wtdomadmin->WTRegister();

}
?>
```

**class_admin.php**

```
function __construct() 
    {

        //Instantiate the API that will construct our admin pages
        $this->settings = new ApiWpadmin();

        //Array of pages to create
        $this->pages = [
            [
                'page_title' => 'My plugin settings page', 
                'menu_title' => 'Settings page', 
                'capability' => 'manage_options', 
                'menu_slug'  => 'wtdomaincheck', 
                'callback'   => array($this, 'WTLoadSettingTemplate'), 
                'icon_url'   => 'dashicons-admin-generic', 
                'position'   => 117
            ]
        ];
        
    
        //Register the settings in the database
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'WTSaveSettings'));
    }



    //
    // PARAM
    // Register all the actions & filters for wp-admin
    //
    public function WTRegister() 
    {

        $this->settings->
            WTAddPages( $this->pages ) ->
            WTWithSubPage( 'Dashboard' ) ->
            WTAddSubPages( $this->subpages ) ->
            WTRegister();

    }


    //
    // PARAM
    // Register the settings values in the database
    //
    public function WTSaveSettings()
    {
            $wt_options = array (
                'display-on-free'       => $_POST['display-on-free'],
                'display-on-registered' => $_POST['display-on-registered'],
                'display-on-invalid'    => $_POST['display-on-invalid'],
                'before-whois-output'   => $_POST['before-whois-output'],
                'after-whois-output'    => $_POST['after-whois-output'],
                'callurl'               => $_POST['callurl'],
                'varname'               => $_POST['varname'],
                'resp-free-domain'      => $_POST['resp-free-domain'],
                'resp-registered-domain'=> $_POST['resp-registered-domain'],
                'resp-invalid-domain'   => $_POST['resp-invalid-domain'],
                'custom-css'            => $_POST['custom-css'],
                'license-key'           => $_POST['license-key'],
                'style-box-bgcolor'     => $_POST['style-box-bgcolor'],
                'style-www-color'       => $_POST['style-www-color'],
                'style-button-color'    => $_POST['style-button-color'],
                'style-button-bgcolor'  => $_POST['style-button-bgcolor'],
                'style-result-color'    => $_POST['style-result-color'],
                'style-result-bgcolor'  => $_POST['style-result-bgcolor']
            );

            if (isset($_POST['enable-multiple-search'])) 
                $wt_options[] = array('enable-multiple-search' => $_POST['enable-multiple-search'] );

            if (isset($_POST['show-www'])) 
                $wt_options[] = array('show-www' => $_POST['show-www'] );

            if (isset($_POST['show-whois-output'])) 
                $wt_options[] = array('show-whois-output' => $_POST['show-whois-output'] );

            update_option( 'wtdomaincheck', $wt_options );
    }



    //
    // PARAM
    // Loads the template that shows the settings page
    //
    public function WTLoadSettingTemplate()
    {
        
        require_once WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_DIR.'admin/html/settings.php';
    }

?>
```

**settings.php**

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php settings_fields( 'wtdomaincheck' ); ?>

        <div class="row border">
            
            <div class="col-3 border-right pt-3 pb-3">
                <div id="pillTabs" class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <?php
                    //Build Pill Sections
                    echo $wtdomadmin->WTBuildPillTabs($sections);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-9 pt-3">
                <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                    <?php
                    //Build Pill Sections
                    echo $wtdomadmin->WTBuildPillPanes($sections);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class='form-group row mx-auto mt-3'>
            <div class="col-lg-12 pr-0">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

When I install the plugin, the options record is created in the wp_options table. The settings page is displayed.. but when I try to save the changes... is where the options page not found comes to the screen...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in my file `settings.php` (which renders the form). Look at the form action. It says `action="options.php"` and then the `settings_field()` inserts a hidden field with the correct action. But WordPress prioritizes the form action, so, when submit the form, WordPress tries to load `options.php` instead of the correct action in the hidden field.

The solution? Simple:

Replace in the form `action="options.php"` by `action=""`.

This simple patch fixes the error.